# regex help - ignore a char if it's in quotes

Tags: regex, csv

We have a web-based app at work where you can enter a regex into a search box and it returns the matches from a database

Here's a sample of what the database entries might look like.  They're comma delimited (think of each record as a family - each family could have between 1 and n entries):

```
record1: "john doe"<john@email.com>;male,"jane doe"<jane@email.com;female
record2: "john smith"<jsmith@email.com>
record3: "smith, jane"<jane@smith.com>
```

What I need to do is enter a regex, so I only get the first entry.  In a working scenario, the output would be everything up to the delimiter:

```
record1: "john doe"<john@email.com>;male
record2: "john smith"<jsmith@email.com>
record3: "smith, jane"<jane@smith.com>
```

In reality, all my attempts are seeing the comma in "smith, jane" as the delimiter.

How do I ignore a comma if it's in quotes?  (For future-proofing, the ability to ignore commas in single-quotes would be good too)

I can *only* use regex, not awk/sed etc and the flavour of regex is POSIX Extended.

Comment: What regex flavor does that web app use?

Comment: We would really need to know the language you are using to answer properly. You might, though, be able to use `,"` as the delimiter instead of simple `,` and then print the return value as `print "$return` to get the quotes back.

Comment: @OliverCFC, See if you've got enough reputation to refine your original question now. Don't change the intent of the question though. Once done, you can delete your comment here.

Answer (score 1):

Highlight: you *do* need to detail your environment a bit more like the comments point out.

Here is one try on my Unix shell with `sed`
Yes, I know you don't want `sed`, but it might help you construct the regex in your environment.

```
data.txt: 
"john doe"<john@email.com>;male,"jane doe"<jane@email.com;female
john_doe"<john@email.com>;male,"jane doe"<jane@email.com;female

# sed -n 's|^\("[^"]\+"[^,]\+\).*|\1| p' data.txt 
"john doe"<john@email.com>;male
```

The regex idea here is to jump over the first pair of double quotes and then look for the comma.
It will fail if there are no double quotes.
It can be scaled to use single quotes.

**Update**:
Look for an `@` followed by `,`...

```
data.txt: 
"john doe"<john@email.com>;male,"jane doe"<jane@email.com;female
john_doe"<john@email.com>;male,"jane doe"<jane@email.com;female

# sed -n 's|\([^@]\+[^,]\+\),.*|\1| p' data.txt 
"john doe"<john@email.com>;male
john_doe<john@email.com>;male
```

Now you get both the cases and then also those w/o the string name or even `<>` wrap.
But, your problem is dependence on the `,` -- breaks for record2 and record3 where you have a single email and no comma. Would still work if you forced a `,` at the end of every record.

Answer (score 1):

[You cannot reliably do this with regular expressions](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=202786). The best you'll be able to do will be an ugly hack based on a bunch of assumptions which are guaranteed to break eventually if you dare put such code into production. (If you can't do it with the firepower of a fully armed and operational Perl regex engine, then you certainly can't do it with POSIX extended regexes.)

In short, to reliably solve this problem, you are going to need to find some way to extend whatever code you're working with so that it can make use of a CSV parsing library, or failing that, you are going to need to write a parser.

Of course, if you're unable to modify the code that's handling the files in question, then you're stuck with the ugly hacks, which in this case is unfortunate as I don't see any really reliable way to produce the desired result with POSIX regexes as your only tool.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to ignore a comma inside quotation marks is problematic because the comma you wish to find is also "in quotation marks" (the end quotation of `"john doe"` and the open quotation of `"jane doe"`). Unless you assume that the first quotation exists, you will have a hard time making this distinction.

Try this instead:

```
^[^<]+<[^>]*>[^,\s]*
```

I'm assuming each record will have an `<email>` and any comma after the email will indicate a new record.  This is just trading one assumption for another, but it worked in my test.

Comment: So, how about looking for an `@` and then stopping at the `,` following it? The assumptions now reduce to: (1) there will be no `@` in the first double quoted string, (2) there will be at most one `@` in the email part -- with or without the `<>` wrap. Note that this allows for there being no quoted string string too.

Comment: It seems we're just trying to find the least bad (i.e. least likely to fail) assumption. Without knowing what data validation is in place on the source database, all we can do is guess.

Comment: this one is working on the most common examples I have.   The main issue is that the first field is free-form and can be *anything* and there is no validation on the source data.  We accept whatever is sent.  You've got it spot on, BTW - I'm trying to find the expression that will produce the most appropriate responses - I understand there probably isn't a true answer

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to change the , delimiter if outside quotes with something else like tab:

Pattern  ((?:[^,"]|"[^"]*")+),
Replace  \1\t

Then split by new delimiter